# simplexml - List inside List

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I have this XML code

```
<data>
     <element>qwe</element>
     <list1>
         <element1>el1</element1>
         <element2>el2</element2>
         <list2 attribute="1"></list2>
         <list2 attribute="q"></list2>
         <list2 attribute="d"></list2>
     </list1>
     <list1>
         <element1>el3</element1>
         <element2>el4</element2>
         <list2 attribute="z"></list2>
     </list1>
</data>
```

I'm using Java and Simple Framework to read that code, but it's throwing some error:

> Element 'List2' is already used with
>   @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList

My Java code is

```
@Root
public class data {
    @Element
    private String element;
    @ElementList
    private List<List1> list1;
}


@Root
class List1 {
    @Element
    private String element1;
    @Element
    private String element2;
    @ElementList (required=false)
    private List<List2> list2;
}

@Root
class List2 {
    @Attribute
    private String attribute;
}
```

How can I read a list inside a list?

Comment: What version of simple are you using? I've tested with 2.7.1 and code works fine.

Comment: I'm also using 2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

Solved

```
@Root
public class data {
    @Element
    private String element;
    @ElementList
    private List<List1> data;
}


@Root (inline=true)
class List1 {
    @Element
    private String element1;
    @Element
    private String element2;
    @ElementList (required=false)
    private List<List2> list1;
}

@Root (inline=true)
class List2 {
    @Attribute
    private String attribute;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible solution @Root annotation doesn't have inline parameter, so it can't work, at least in version 2.7.1 of SimpleXML library.

Comment: @ATom is right. The correct @Root annotation should look like this `@Root(name = "List2", strict = false)`